# Auth0 and angular2: how to set callbackURL and catch the token?

Tags: authentication, angular, angular2-routing, auth0

I am trying to implement passwordless authentication with [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and [angular2](https://angular.io/) (2.0.0-rc.6), using [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and [auth0-lock-passwordless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0-lock-passwordless).

The form displays normally, and the authentication e-mail is sent using this code:

```
this.lock.magiclink({
    callbackURL:"http://localhost:3000/#/sandbox"
    });
```

The issues occur *after* I click the magic link in the e-mail:

- Even though the redirect_uri of the magic link seems correct (redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%23%2Fsandbox), it is ignored;
- Instead, after a successful login (checked in Auth0 logs), the url in the address bar is (briefly): 
  http://localhost:3000/#access_token=xxxxxxxxxx&id_token=yyyyyyyyy&email=myemail@emails.com (notice the # instead of expected question mark)
- then (after a second or so) it redirects to: http://localhost:3000/#/access_token

---

> My questions are:
>
> 1. How to have Auth0 actually redirect to callbackURL?
> 2. How can I catch the token with the new angular2 router, even though the uri is misformed? (question mark missing before the query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much struggling, I found a workaround.

**TL;DR; use PathLocationStrategy (HTML 5 pushState), not the "hash URL" style.**

---

Below `Allowed logout URLs` and `Allowed origins` in the Auth0 console (Clients settings), it is specified:

> Notice that querystrings and hash information are not taken into account when validating these URLs.

So I figured it might apply to `Allowed Callback URLs` as well, even though it was not specified.

That would explain why `callbackURL` is ignored.

---

The trick is then to get rid of the hash (#) in the URLs; the hash is the default `LocationStrategy` in [Angular2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter).

To do that, in `app.modules.ts`, change `RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })` to `RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: false })`

---

Although it should have worked, I came accross yet another issue: when you reload a page, it gives a blank page with the following message:

```
<% if (webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags) { %>
```

After a little Googling, I found a [fix in this page](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/1056).

The fix is to remove the carret (^) in the "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.2" (devDependencies, package.json), and reinstall the package:

- replace "^2.1.0-beta.2" by "2.1.0-beta.2"

then, in console/terminal, type: `npm install webpack-dev-server`

---

Now all I had to do was to update the callbackURL like so:

```
this.lock.magiclink({
  callbackURL:"http://localhost:3000/sandbox"
});
```

And in Auth0 Clients settings' Allowed Callback URLs, insert:

```
http://localhost:3000/sandbox
```

and save.

Now, after a successful login (when I click the magic link in the e-mail), it opens a browser window with following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/sandbox#access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx&id_token=yyyyyyyyyyy&token_type=Bearer
```

and it stays there, as it should. Catching and saving the token should now be trivial...